# Vibration after touch the screen

Tags: android, touchscreen, vibration

I am working on an app which starts to vibrate after the application is opened for 3000 ms. I have these two lines of code:

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 v.vibrate(3000);
```

I want to write an android code which starts vibrating after a user touch a screen. Please help me.

Comment: That code should work. Did you set permissions?     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

Answer (score 3):

In your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        yourVibrateFunction();
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked.  However, instead of posting 'Thanks' in a comment, mark answers as accepted.